# How to write String.raw() with normal JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, template-literals

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw#description),

> String.raw() is the only built-in template literal tag. It has close semantics to an untagged literal since it concatenates all arguments and returns a string. ***You can even re-implement it with normal JavaScript code.***

How would you "re-implement String.raw() with normal JavaScript code"? If I write my own template literal function `const raw = (s, v) => ...`, the string array `s` contains strings that are no longer raw. For example,

```
raw `a\nb`
```

will pass a-newline-b, whereas the raw string would be a-backslash-n-b.

My raw() template literal function could reverse the quoting by turning newline into backslash-n, but that's not reliable. How does it distinguish between:

```
raw `a\nb`
```

and

```
raw `a
b`
```

?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#raw_strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array that is passed as first argument to the template tag function has an additional property `raw`, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#raw_strings). It contains the same as `strings` itself but as raw strings, without parsing escape sequences.

This means that `String.raw` could be replicated as follows:

```js
function myRaw (strings, ...values) {
  return strings.raw.reduce((result, s, i) => result + s + (values[i] ?? ''), '')
}
```

Note that if we'd replace `strings.raw.reduce` with just `strings.reduce`, we'd get a "do-nothing" template tag function.

Comment: Good answer. For time complexity, it would be better to write this as `map` + `join` though (linear vs. quadratic time in the number of strings).

Comment: If you want to make it shorter: `.reduce((acc, s, i) => acc + arguments[i] + s)` (without the initial value, since `strings` and `strings.raw` are never empty)

Comment: @Luatic All modern JS engines can build strings by repeated appending without quadratic time complexity

Comment: @Bergi as long as this isn't in the spec and there are spec-compliant JS engines that do otherwise, it's worst case quadratic time complexity in my book. Immutable strings simply aren't "array lists of characters".

Comment: @Luatic Nothing in the spec requires engines to optimise `join` to have linear time complexity either

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the raw property. Yes, it's there in the documentation.

There is always one more string than value, so `return values.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc + v + strings.raw[i + 1]), strings.raw[0])`

Comment: `let raw = (s, ...v) => v.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc + v + s.raw[i + 1], s.raw[0])`

Answer (score 1):

For this to work properly, you have to make use of the [`raw` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#raw_strings) of the first argument to the template function. It contains an array of the raw contents of the string as it exists in the source code, without backslash being treated as an escape character.

For example:

```
function raw(strings, ...values) {
  const output = [];
 
  for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    output.push(strings.raw[i]);  // <== instead of strings[i]
    if (i < values.length) {
      output.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return output.join("");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `toString` be a `join("")` to not delimit using `,`?

Comment: Right you are, I misremembered the behaviour of `toString` and then didn't test it with any interpolation.